# How to define proguard to keep java interface for IMEI (using Phonegap for Android)?

Tags: java, android, cordova, proguard, cordova-plugin-proguard

I've been searching (this site and others) for an answer for a couple weeks now.
I'm pretty sure my problem lies with how I've defined my keep options in the proguard-project.txt.

I've added a javainterface to my app so it's able to use TelephonyManager to get the IMEI.
This works fine when I dont use ProGuard in the build.
When I use Proguard, the getIMEI function doesnt work anymore.

Here's the GetNativeTelephonyManager.java code:

```
package com.abc.myapp1;

import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;
import android.content.Context;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class GetNativeTelephonyManager {
    private WebView mAppView;
    private DroidGap mGap;
    public GetNativeTelephonyManager(DroidGap gap, WebView view){
        mAppView = view;
        mGap = gap;
    }   
    public String getIMEI(){
        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) mGap.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        String imeiId = tm.getDeviceId();      
        return imeiId;
    }
}
```

Here's the MainActivity.java code:

```
package com.abc.myapp1;

import android.os.Bundle;

import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;

public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {

    GetNativeTelephonyManager gntm;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.init();
        gntm = new GetNativeTelephonyManager(this, appView);
        appView.addJavascriptInterface(gntm, "GetNativeTelephonyManager");
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }
}
```

Here's the proguard-project.txt options:

```
-keep public class * extends com.phonegap.api.Plugin 
-keep public class * extends org.apache.cordova.api.Plugin 
-keep public class org.apache.cordova.DroidGap 
-keep public class org.apache.cordova.** 

-keep public class **.GetNativeTelephonyManager { *; }
-keepclassmembers public class **.GetNativeTelephonyManager { *; }

-libraryjars libs/cordova-2.1.0.jar
-dontwarn android.webkit.*
-dontwarn org.apache.**
```

Using dex2jar and JD-GUI, I've been able to inspect the MainActivity and GetNativeTelephonyManager classes after proguard has run.
The code has changed slightly, and when I run the app on my device, the imei is no longer available when I use window.GetNativeTelephonyManager.getIMEI()

Here's the MainActivity.java after proguard:

```
package com.abc.myapp1;

import android.os.Bundle;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView;
import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;

public class MainActivity
  extends DroidGap
{
  GetNativeTelephonyManager a;

  public void onCreate(Bundle paramBundle)
  {
    super.onCreate(paramBundle);
    super.b();
    this.a = new GetNativeTelephonyManager(this, this.d);
    this.d.addJavascriptInterface(this.a, "GetNativeTelephonyManager");
    super.a("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
  }
}
```

Here's the GetNativeTelephonyManager.java after proguard:

```
package com.abc.myapp1;

import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;

public class GetNativeTelephonyManager
{
  private WebView mAppView;
  private DroidGap mGap;

  public GetNativeTelephonyManager(DroidGap paramDroidGap, WebView paramWebView)
  {
    this.mAppView = paramWebView;
    this.mGap = paramDroidGap;
  }

  public String getIMEI()
  {
    return ((TelephonyManager)this.mGap.getSystemService("phone")).getDeviceId();
  }
}
```

It's been driving me nuts.
I'm sure this has been done before, but I can't find the answer.
Would really appreciate a little help.
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, the above was fine.
I had changed my target to android-19.
For android target >= 17, you need to add @JavascriptInterface to each method you want to use from javascript.

Note: you also need to add: import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;

So the GetNativeTelephonyManager.java code is now:

```
import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;
import android.content.Context;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;

public class GetNativeTelephonyManager {
    private WebView mAppView;
    private DroidGap mGap;
    public GetNativeTelephonyManager(DroidGap gap, WebView view){
        mAppView = view;
        mGap = gap;
    }
    @JavascriptInterface
    public String getIMEI(){
        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) mGap.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        String imeiId = tm.getDeviceId();      
        return imeiId;
    }
}
```

Hope the above helps anyone else that runs into the same problem.